# How to format text within the Thunderbird Conversations view?

Tags: fonts, thunderbird, text

I am  trying to make a move from gmail to my own email, and for this I am testing Thunderbird on Ubuntu. Since I really like the gmail style I installed the Conversations view extension. So far so good.

Today I was writing an email though, and I could not find any formatting options. When I switch off the conversations view I've got the formatting options again, but with the Conversations view enabled I can't see them. Also, normal key-combinations like Ctrl+b and Ctrl+i don't do anything.

Does anybody know how I can make text bold or italic in the conversations view?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author. Unfortunately, the inline reply feature of Thunderbird Conversations only provides support for a plaintext reply, not an HTML one. This would require significantly more work, for which I lack the time and the motivation.

Thanks,

jonathan

Comment: Hi Jonathan. First of all; thanks for creating it! I think it is a brilliant extension! Of course a pity that you lack the time and motivation for supporting html-mails. I just downloaded the source and had a look at it. Although I am more used to Python I do have a little experience in html, css, and javascript. Would you have any pointers in where to start? Wouldn't it be possible to simply include a wysiwyg editor like TinyMCE? If you would like to put a little effort into it I (and maybe others?) would love to help you out..

Comment: Can you add your email address to your stack exchange profile or contact me by email so that we can continue the discussion? Thanks! :)

Comment: I already had my email address on my account here, but you don't seem to be able to make it publicly viewable (or at least, I don't seem to be able to) and I also don't see an email address on your account page. Why don't you send send me a PM on the UbuntuForums.org and we'll take it from there: http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=228611

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am intruding or much late, but you can also clic "Reply" above your message : your reply appears with normal formatting features, and after you send it, you have it integrated in the conversation.

... Well this is with the Windows 7 version of ThunderBird.

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer comes a little bit late, but I just recently started to use Thunderbird Conversations and faced the same problem.
I solved the problem by looking for a way to switch between plain text and HTML messages. This can be done by pressing the SHIFT-Button while clicking on reply, reply all, forward, etc. ...

So with Thunderbird Conversations, as Jonathan said, the standard would be plain text, but by pressing SHIFT while clicking, you would end up with an HTML message. After opening the composer this way, all shortcuts should work and the formatting toolbar should be shown as well.

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce what JJV wrote, I still end up with a plain text message if I hit reply above the message without pressing the SHIFT-Button